# What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

I have been seeing this error in the console:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'touchstart' of undefined
> at String.<anonymous> (jquery.mobile.customized.min.js:10)
> at Function.each (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:2)
> at jquery.mobile.customized.min.js:10
> at jquery.mobile.customized.min.js:10
> at window.define (jquery.mobile.customized.min.js:10)
> at jquery.mobile.customized.min.js:10
> ```

Does anyone know what this mean and how I can solve it?

Looking forward to hear from you! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you give us the code where you use 'touchstart' ? The error say "You try to use touchstart on something which is undefined"

Comment: It seems like you have a bit of js that uses the jquery touchstart event. This event is problematic as only chrome fully supports it. As a guess, your jquery.mobile.customized.min.js is probably not compatible with jquery-1.10.2.min.js. So I quess again, you are using a theme or module that is outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer @YiorgosMoschovitis. I believe that you are correct about the outdated theme/module. Could you please suggest what I can do to solve this? The theme that I use is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you use something like that :

```
myVar.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    // code
}, false)
```

But **myVar** is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Search your codebase for `touchstart`, and make sure each variable/element you're using `touchstart` on is defined.